# How to set textview width for different screen size width in Android?

Tags: android

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/width_chat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
            android:fontFamily="calibri"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#636363"
            android:background="@anim/mercy"
            android:textSize="17dp" />
```

This is my text view. I have screen size 4 and 6 inch. I want to set width so that according to that it should auto adjust. I have created 2 dimension files in `values` and `values-sw600dp`. In both folder I have set dimension width 250dp and  and 150 respectively but unable to set size according to different files. Please help me and suggest me where am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you have width values in correct dimens.xml file? If width is not set according to the param you set in the file, that means you are setting values in wrong file.

Comment: see i have 2 device  we have folder values,values-sw600dp,values-sw720dp-land,values-v11,values-v14 i have to set for this

Answer (score 1):

Use a Horizontal `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight` property to each child.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to use dimensions files(e.g. to set `text_size`), enter the values in `dimens.xml` in the appropriate folder.

```
res/values/dimens.xml
res/values-small/dimens.xml
res/values-normal/dimens.xml
res/values-large/dimens.xml
res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
```

Comment: cant we use dimension file ?

Answer (score 1):

You might simply also try to define the dimensions in 'px' instead of 'dp'.. However, assigning weight is always a better solution..